# SharePoint 2016 search full crawl never ends

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I have 6 content sources in my SharePoint 2016 - all content sources have been running without any issues over the last 3 years. But suddenly we notice that out of 6, in 4 content source crawler is running fine (incremental and Full crawl) but 2 content sources are not running properly - the incremental crawls stuck for these two content sources - so, we have stopped this using the PowerShell, after this automatically full crawl starts for this 2 content source but it never ends, continue for more than 100 hours. Then if we stop again using the PowerShell script, it will start full crawling again but will never end.

Till now we have done the followings:

- Restarted the search service and timer services in the application
  server many times.
- Restarted the server couple of times
- Cleared the cache from both the application and frond end server
  (Following the Microsoft documentation)
- Did IIS Reset
- Did server restarts

After doing all the above, nothing helped us to fix the issue. Now, we request your help and suggestion to fix this issue.

**Answer Update - found the answer or troubleshooting this issue in October 2022**

After a long struggling found the answers and could fix the search crawling issue without deleting or re-creating the search service application, I thought that sharing this might be helpful to someone.

**Let's understand why search crawl never ends in SharePoint.**

First, let’s understand the SharePoint Search database. When we create a search service application in the SharePoint application server, in the SQL backend, the below database will be created automatically:

- **Crawl database**
- Link database
- Analytics reporting database
- Search administration database

All the databases will be created in the below format:

- <Search_Service Application_Name>_Crawl_GUID
- <Search_Service Application_Name>_Link_GUID
- <Search_Service Application_Name>_Analytics_GUID
- <Search_Service Application_Name>_SearchAdministration_GUID

The SharePoint’s full crawl never ends issue lies in the **Crawl database**. If we open this database from the SQL server, we can see the below table:

**Table Name: MSSCrawlURL**

In this table along with many columns, we have the column “**ErrorCount**” whose type is “smallint”, and the “smallint” datatype can hold a maximum value of **32767** (smallint range is “**-32,768**” to “**32767**”).

The problem is here in this “**ErrorCount**” column, while full crawl runs and that generates plenty of crawl errors – all details get logged to this MSSCrawlURL table. When the search service application is no more able to add any records in this table while running the full or incremental crawl as the “**ErrorCount**” value reached the max (**32767**), in this scenario, the crawler goes on the infinite loop which never ends.

**How to fix this issue?**

Login to the SQL server and open the crawl database, update the “**ErrorCount**” column value from **32767** to **1** wherever it reached the max. If you are an expert in SQL database administration you can handle it otherwise take help from the SQL database administration team. Then using the below PowerShell scripts, stop the crawl (Full and Incremental whichever running), and restart the search and timer service in the application server.

Then don’t do anything, leave it as its – from the next craw schedule the SharePoint search crawl will be running as usual without any issues.

Reference article: [[Fixed]: SharePoint full crawl never ends – Revealed the technical reasons Why SharePoint Search Crawler never ends](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/sharepoint-full-crawl-never-ends/)

Comment: Hammer down - reset the search index. Might be the fix - or else you might need to rebuild you search service from scratch if it's corrupted.

Comment: Hi @Christoffer - Thanks for your comment, know about it, looking for any other hopes without going to resetting or re-creating the SSA. :-)

Comment: How many servers do you have and what are their roles in the farm?

Comment: @CallumCrowley - We have two servers one is an app with search another is wfe

Comment: Hi @Christoffer - Happy to share with you, today I was able to fix this without re-indexing or rebuilding the search service - troubleshooting details added to the updated question section.